# does freezing early layers of a NN stop it's forward propagation also?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm using Keras.

I know that freezing early layers stops the computation of backprop, but it seems like if the forward prop of the early layers is computed every step during training then the same thing is just being computed up until it reaches the unfrozen layers.

If the forward prop is computed every step for the frozen layers then isnt it a waste of computation time? since the same thing is being computed every step.

does anyone know an option that will only compute the outputs from the frozen layers once and use those outputs from the frozen layers to train the unfrozen layers?

Answer (score 0):

The output of the frozen layers is not always the same, since it depends on the input of the network. Freezing a layer only means that you do not use backpropagation to calculate the gradients and update the weights of these layers, i.e. only the weights of the frozen layers stay the same.

Comment: the output of the frozen layers is the same for the same input, and as you're using the same data for each epoch the outputs are going to be the same

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments the frozen portion of your network is used in forward propagation but its weights are not updated during back propagation. This reduces computation time for back propagation. It would be a lot of work but it is possible to accomplish what you want. You would have to run your entire input data set and capture the outputs from the last frozen  layer. Then use these saved values as inputs to your untrained network.

Comment: yep but training would be a lot faster :P, especially for deep NNs